# How can I change several Active Directory user passwords?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm trying to programaticaly change several user's password, specifically without using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement (PrincipalContext)
I have this piece of working code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace ADScriptService.core
{
    class ExportTool
    {
        const AuthenticationTypes = AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.Sealing | AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind;
        private static DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ADScriptService.Properties.Settings.Default.ActiveDirectoryPath, ADScriptService.Properties.Settings.Default.ServerAdminUser, ADScriptService.Properties.Settings.Default.ServerAdminPwd, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        private static DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
    public void Export()
    {

        string path = ADScriptService.Properties.Settings.Default.ActiveDirectoryPath;
        string adminUser = ADScriptService.Properties.Settings.Default.ServerAdminUser;
        string adminPassword = ADScriptService.Properties.Settings.Default.ServerAdminPwd;

        string userName = "exampleUser";
        string newPassword = "P455w0rd";
        try
        {
            search.Filter = String.Format("sAMAccountName={0}", userName);
            search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            search.CacheResults = false;
            SearchResult searchResult = search.FindOne();
            if (searchResult == null) Console.WriteLine("User Not Found In This Domain");
            DirectoryEntry userEntry = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();

            userEntry.Path = userEntry.Path.Replace(":389", "");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("sAMAccountName={0}, User={1}, path={2}", userEntry.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value, userEntry.Username, userEntry.Path));
            userEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { newPassword });
            userEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x0200 | 0x10000;
            userEntry.CommitChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("Se ha cambiado la contraseña");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is an example with a single user, but what my program should do is iterate through ~120k users.
However, the operation of setting the search filter, finding one result and getting the DirectoryEntry takes about 2 or 3 seconds per user so I'm trying to use the DirectoryEntries structure given by the DirectoryEntry.Children property, which means replacing the six lines after "try{" with simply `DirectoryEntry userentry = directoryEntry.Children.Find("CN=" + userName);`

So the example's code would look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace ADScriptService.core
{
    class ExportTool
    {
        const AuthenticationTypes = AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.Sealing | AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind;
        private static DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ADScriptService.Properties.Settings.Default.ActiveDirectoryPath, ADScriptService.Properties.Settings.Default.ServerAdminUser, ADScriptService.Properties.Settings.Default.ServerAdminPwd, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        private static DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
    public void Export()
    {

        string path = ADScriptService.Properties.Settings.Default.ActiveDirectoryPath;
        string adminUser = ADScriptService.Properties.Settings.Default.ServerAdminUser;
        string adminPassword = ADScriptService.Properties.Settings.Default.ServerAdminPwd;

        string userName = "exampleUser";
        string newPassword = "P455w0rd";
        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry userEntry = directoryEntry.Children.Find("CN=" + userName);

            userEntry.Path = userEntry.Path.Replace(":389", "");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("sAMAccountName={0}, User={1}, path={2}", userEntry.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value, userEntry.Username, userEntry.Path));
            userEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { newPassword });
            userEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x0200 | 0x10000;
            userEntry.CommitChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("Se ha cambiado la contraseña");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

But this code gets the following error in the invocation line `(userEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { newPassword });`:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The RPC server is unavailable. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
```

which in english means RCP server unavailable. I've been stuck here for some days, and I've only found that it can be because of some authentication problem.
Invoking the method "Groups" works (`userEntry.Invoke("Groups");`) and the administrator, which is the user I'm loging in with to the ActiveDirectory has all the privileges. Also the password policy is completly permissive with no minimum lenght or complexity.

Again, because the program must iterate through, the real program actually iterates through the DirectoryEntry's children with:

```
foreach(DirectoryEntry child in directoryEntry.Children) 
{
    child.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { newPassword });
    child.CommitChanges();
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: please translate the exception messages to English...

Comment: Done, I've already translasted them

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using `directoryEntry.Children.Find("CN=" + userName)` will give you much performance improvement. The `sAMAccountName` attribute is an indexed attribute, so the search is very fast. That's one of the fastest searches you can make.

But note that your two code blocks are not equal. `Find("CN=" + userName)` is trying to match `userName` to the name of the account: the `cn` attribute. But your code block with the `DirectorySearcher` is matching `userName` to the `sAMAccountName` attribute. The `cn` and `sAMAccountName` attributes are not necessarily the same (although they might be in your domain).

But, if you still want to use `Children.Find()`, I suspect that the problem might be in your `Path` of the `DirectoryEntry`. Why are you doing this?

```
userEntry.Path = userEntry.Path.Replace(":389", "");
```

Does your `ADScriptService.Properties.Settings.Default.ActiveDirectoryPath` have `:389`? It doesn't need to if it starts with `LDAP://` (the default LDAP port is 389).

Your `userEntry.Path` should look something like (depending on your domain) `LDAP://CN=user,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com`. If it's not, then you need to fix that.

A side note: There is something you can do to speed this up a lot more than changing the search. The `Properties` collection uses a cache. When you access a property, it checks if it is already in the cache and, if so, uses the cache. But if the property is not in the cache, then it will ask Active Directory for *every attribute that has a value*. That is expensive and unnecessary if you only want to read one or two attributes (especially if you're doing it for thousands of accounts).

A way around this is to tell it to get only the attributes that you want using `RefreshCache`, before you access any of the `Properties`. Like this:

```
userEntry.RefreshCache(new [] { "sAMAccountName", "userAccountControl" });
```

Then when you access those properties, it will already have them in the cache and not reach out to AD to get anything.

Also, if you are running this in a big loop over thousands of accounts, then I suggest you put the `DirectoryEntry` in a `using` statement (or call `userEntry.Dispose()` when you're done with it). Usually you don't need to since garbage collection is pretty good at cleaning them up. But because you're running a big loop, the garbage collector doesn't have a chance to do any cleaning, so your process can end up taking up more and more and more memory until the loop finally stops. I have had big jobs like this take several GB of memory until I started disposing the unused `DirectoryEntry` objects.

*Update:* Actually, forget about what I said about the `DirectoryEntry` above. You don't actually need to use the `DirectoryEntry` at all. Don't use `searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry()`. The problem here is that you've already made a search to find the account. But now you're creating a `DirectoryEntry`, which is just going to make another call out to AD to get information you already have. That's probably where your main performance hit is.

Instead, use the attributes returned from your search. Now, just like `DirectoryEntry.Properties`, if you don't specify which attributes you want returned in the search, then it will return all of them, which you don't necessarily need. So you should set the `PropertiesToLoad` collection, like this:

```
search.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new [] { "sAMAccountName", "userAccountControl" });
```

Then, after the search, you can use this to get the `sAMAccountName` of the account you found:

```
searchResult.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In fact the two searches are not equal, but they find the same DirectoryEntry object (in this case the sAMAccountName and the CN are the same). I've now tried `using (DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(...)`, then perform the search with the DirectorySearcher filtering by SamAccountName but still getting the error "The RCP server is unavailable"

Comment: What is `ADScriptService.Properties.Settings.Default.ActiveDirectoryPath` set to? It should be something like `LDAP://domain.com`

Comment: It is set to `LDAP://192.168.13.99:389/CN=Users,DC=ejemplo,DC=com`.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an IP address instead of your domain name? You should be able to just use `LDAP://ejemplo.com/CN=Users,DC=ejemplo,DC=com`

Comment: It's a remote domain, trying to use that it returns: `El servidor no es funcional.`, which translates as "The server is not functional".

Comment: You said it worked before when you were using the `DirectorySearcher`, no?

Comment: Yes, but only creating a new `DirectorySearcher` object for each `DirectoryEntry` in the domain.

Comment: Right, that's fine. You should probably go back to that. Then change your code to use `RefreshCache` like I described in my answer. You should get much better performance doing that.

Comment: I was thinking about this again, and I realized that you don't even need to use `searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry()`, and that's probably what's slowing you down the most. I added an update to the end of my answer.

Comment: To find the user it works just like you say, but how can I then set the password? I think the only way to invoke the method is through a DirectoryEntry object. What seems to work now is to set the `userEntry`'s authentication type to secure: `userEntry.AuthenticationType = authenticationTypes;` where `const AuthenticationTypes authenticationTypes = AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.Sealing | AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind;`, but it gets even slower.

Comment: Right. To set the password, you can use `searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry()`, just don't use the `Properties` of the `DirectoryEntry` since as soon as you do, it will ask AD for *all* attributes, which will slow things down. If you just call `.Invoke("SetPassword" ...` then you should be fine.

Comment: Are you still getting an exception on the call to `.Invoke`?

Comment: Yes, still getting the same exception

Comment: Are you sure the domain controller you are using is a writable DC?

Comment: Yes, by creating new `SearchResult`s and each one with it's respective `DirectoryEntry` it works. Also whenever I test using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` I'm able to commit changes. However in the final version of the program I'm not allowed to do so.

Comment: "by creating new SearchResults and each one with it's respective DirectoryEntry it works" - That's fine then. Do it that way. Just don't use the `Properties` of the `DirectoryEntry` so you don't pull all the attributes from AD a second time.